# True or false statement about a $C^\infty$ function

Tags: analysis

If $f \in  C^\infty$ and $f^k(0)=0 \forall$  $k \in \mathbb N \bigcup \{0\}$,then can we conclude that $f$ is identically zero?

Comment: What's $\mathbb C^\infty$?

Comment: Try $f(x) = e^{-x^{-2}}$ for $x\neq0$, $f(0)=0$.

Comment: @azarel OP probably meant $\mathcal{C}^\infty$, the class of infinitely differentiable functions

Comment: even $f^k(x)=0$ for any $k\geq 0$, $x\in [0,1]$ does not imply $f\equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score -3):

What does mean $\mathbb{C}^\infty$? If you wanted to say just $C^\infty$, then the answer to your question is negative as Matthew Leingang showed. Another classical example is the following: Consider the function $f(x)=\exp(-\frac{1}{x})$ if $x>0$, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. It is not so difficult to show that $f$ is a $C^\infty$ function on the real line. Moreover, this kind of functions are very interesting because they play an important role in the theory of $C^\infty$ functions. As you easily can note, the examples give them here are functions that are not analytic, they just are smooth functions.